# 2 wordpress installations - problem visiting second installation

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've been digging in stackoverflow and googling before posting and didnt find the proper solution.

I have a main wordpress site which is, domain.com and installed another wordpress site completely independent (because we needed that way) under domain.com/shop.

If I visit `domain.com`, everything works as expected. 
If I visit `domain.com/store`, it shows domain.com website. ERROR here.
If I visit `domain.com/store/index.php`, I can see the new wordpress installation.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it? I know it's refered to `htaccess` but I have no idea how to properly code it.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Try the following htaccess content for `/store/` directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /store/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /store/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Remove /store from the last rule (RewriteBase stays as before).

Answer (score 0):

Remove /store from the last rule (RewriteBase stays as before).

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /store/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```